# Firebase project which uses Google Analytics is not showing any data after more than 24 hours

Tags: javascript, firebase

I initialized firebase project and in my html's body I have all those scripts

```
<script src="/__/firebase/8.3.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/8.3.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
<script src="/js/chunk-vendors.d4f85827.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.9772568a.js"></script>
```

I don't know what else should I do, in my projects settings, I have analytics enabled
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvTof.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.S. Once you have successfully installed the tracking code on your site, it can take up to 24 hours for data to show up in your regular reports.

If your Google Analytics is not working as expected and your data isn’t showing up in reports, you can quickly go through this troubleshooting guide and effectively pinpoint the culprits behind your traffic drop.

https://holini.com/google-analytics-isnt-working/